# How to keep/distribute MySQL data along with the code?

Tags: mysql, local-database

I want to have some database belong exclusively to some program.

I don't want user to install MySQL first, then set some database pathes and so on. Let it be just single install.

I don't claim database engine be embedded, but DATA should. It should not be resided in some global system-wide place.

Comment: Have you considered using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do an SQL dump of the database and include it as a string literal in your program.

From what I understand, you don't want the database engine to be embedded?